# How to pass updated field value into a function(inline edit and update)

Tags: angularjs

I am doing inline edit and update.
`Edit` and `Cancel` functionality working fine.But while updating am unable to pass updated field value into a `update` function,Its showing `undefined` in `console.log`.
What is the issue here?

```
<body ng-app="intranet_App">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="mydata" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <thead class="colorBlue">
      <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="">
      <tr ng-repeat="x in roleList | filter:searchText" ng-model="x.Id">
        <td>{{x.Id}}</td>
        <td>
          <span ng-hide="editMode">{{x.name}}</span>
          <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="x.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <i class="edit fa fa-pencil-square-o" id="edit{{x.Id}}" ng-click="editMode = true;edit(x.Id)" ng-hide="editMode"></i>
          <i class="update fa fa-floppy-o" id="update{{x.Id}}" ng-hide="true" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="update(x.name);editMode = false"></i>
          <i class="editCancel fa fa-times" id="editCancel{{x.Id}}" ng-click="editMode = false" ng-hide="true" ng-show="editMode"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular
    .module("intranet_App", [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.updateItem = [];
      $scope.updatedList = function(val) {
        $scope.updateItem.push(val);
        $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.val);

      }
      $http.post("/Admin/getRolesList")
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.roleList = response.data;
        });
      //$scope.edit=function(val){
      //    $scope.editing = $scope.items.indexOf(val);
      //}
      $scope.update = function(val) {
        console.log(val)
        $scope.updatedList(val);
        var requestHeaders = {
          "Content-type": 'application/json'
        }
        var httpRequest = {
          method: 'post',
          url: '/Admin/RoleUpdate',
          headers: requestHeaders
        };
        httpRequest.data = $scope.json;
        $http(httpRequest).then(function(response) {
          alert("success")
        })
      }
      $scope.cancel = function(val) {
      }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: In the Updated List function of yours, You're using $scope.val in  $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.val); and there is no $scope.val. Change it to $scope.json = angular.toJson(val); only and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `updatedList function`, You have taken `$scope.val` but it should be `val`

Since you are accessing `val` from the function parameter, it will not be in the `scope`,**so `$scope.val` will be undefined**

change `angular.toJson($scope.val);` to `angular.toJson(val);`

```
$scope.updatedList = function (val) {
    $scope.updateItem.push(val);
    $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.val);
    console.log($scope.json)
}
```

Should be,

```
$scope.updatedList = function (val) {
    $scope.updateItem.push(val);
    $scope.json = angular.toJson(val);
    console.log($scope.json)
}
```

**Update as per your need:**,

```
$scope.updatedList = function (val) {
   $scope.updateItem.push(val);
   $scope.json = angular.toJson(val);
   if($scope.json)
    {
      $scope.json = { "name": $scope.json }   
    }
    console.log($scope.json)
}
```

Comment: No in `update` function itself its coming as `undefined`

Comment: how to send it with a key like this..`{ "name":"john" }`

Comment: you want so send to database like that?

Comment: In backend its coming like this `"\" john \""`.....why you are sending `json` again into an object.

Comment: you can take,  `$scope.json = { "name": val }`